# How to exit the application on 3 wrong attempts

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a login page where the No. of attempts is checked. The problem right now is it locks the user but keeps the counter for No. of Attempts increasing. I want to exit stop the counter to be increment. Please Help!

```
<html>
<head><title>Meeting Room Application</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validation()
 {
    var uname=document.forms["Login"]["txtuid"].value;
    var pwd=document.forms["Login"]["txtpwd"].value;
    if((uname==null || uname=="") && (pwd==null || pwd==""))
    {
        alert("Please fill all the details");
        return false;
    }
    if(uname==null || uname=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter username");
        return false;
    }
    if(pwd==null || pwd=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter password");
        return false; 
    }
    if(noofattempt>=3)
        return false;
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body background="a6.jpg">
   <?php
          session_start();
          if(isset($_SESSION['loginattempt']))
          $NoOfAttempt=(int) $_SESSION['loginattempt'];
          else
          $NoOfAttempt=0;
     ?>
      <table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
      <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><img src="LOGO.jpg" width="275px;">     </td></tr>
      <tr><th align="center" colspan="2">Kindly provide Login Details</th</tr>
     <form method="post" name="Login" action="checkdb.php" onsubmit="return validation()" >
     <tr><td align="right"><b>UserId : </td><td><input type="text" name="txtuid" placeholder="user"></td></tr>
      <tr><td align="right"><b>Password : </td><td><input type="password" name="txtpwd" placeholder="*****"></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td>
  <td><font color="red">
  <?php 
      if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
      { 
            echo $_SESSION['error']."<br>"; 
            echo "No Of Attempt ". $NoOfAttempt;
      }
        if($NoOfAttempt>=3)
                echo "<br>Your Account Has been Locked..Contact Admin";
       ?> </font></td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Sign in">
       <input type="reset" value="Reset"><input type="hidden" name='NoOfAttempt' value= <?php echo $NoOfAttempt;  ?> /></td>
         </tr>
         </form>
         </div>
         </div>
         </table>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: Why not have something that checks if the user is locked out or not? if they are, don't update the database. Currently I see nothing implemented that states the user is actually locked out. Also handle the lockout code in PHP instead of javascript, a user can easily disable javascript and submit as many times as they want.

Comment: Sir i have 1 page where i check the attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not retrieving the hidden form value NoOfAttempt in your validation() function.

```
var noofattempt=document.forms["Login"]["NoOfAttempt"].value;
```

*Note that this will stop the user from accidentally submitting the form additional times after the limit has been reached, however as a previous commenter said, this can be easily overridden by someone who is trying to do so, or even possibly just by having Javascript disabled.  So the limit should be enforced somewhere else in your PHP code.*

Comment: Thanks! This has helped. But now this page remains in loop. Suppose another user inserts right username -password then its not redirecting to homepage.

Comment: You should probably just avoid using Javascript to prevent submission after the number of attempts has been reached.  Allow the user to submit the form as many times as they want, but have checkdb.php just display a message instead of processing the login attempt from a particular username after the limit is reached.  This avoids the problem.

Comment: How can i do that ? Plz guide  @wojtow

Comment: This is getting beyond the scope of the original question, which was answered for you.   Another issue to note is that you use the session to keep track of the number of attempts.   If the user supplies a different username, the session will still persist and the the count will remain the same.   If the user clears the cookies, or logs in from a different browser or computer then the original count will not apply and they can try additional attempts.  Would again suggest that you use the database that keeps track of the users to keep track of the counts.  Open a new question if needed.